# Can someone help, i cant fix program that should printf in backwards

Tags: c

My profesor told me to fix it but i dont know what is wrong here.
Please I tried everything but its not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void naopak(char slovo[20][20], int i)
{
    for( i=0; slovo[0][i]!='\0';)
    {
        i++;
    }
    for( i=0; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c",slovo[0][i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char slova[20];
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&slova);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        naopak(slova[i][i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly like the sample in your learning materials

Comment: BTW: `slova[20]` is a one dimensional array, therefore `slova[i][i]` is just plain wrong meaningless

Comment: the code wont even compile. the least you can do is to copy the errors into the question. which is not yo say that it would be sufficient.

Comment: Compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your code (using [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...) to get no warnings then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb) to understand the behavior of your program

Answer (score 1):

Your program is overly complicated and wrong.

You probably want this:

```
void naopak(char slovo[20])
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; slovo[i] != '\0'; i++); // goto end of string

  for (i -= 1; i >= 0; i--)  // i -= 1 decrements i, because i points the NUL terminator
  {
    printf("%c", slovo[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char slova[20];
  scanf("%19s", slova);    // input of word (%19s prevents buffer overflow
                           // if you enter more than 19 chars

  naopak(slova);         // print the word in reverse
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RohanBari yes of course, but `slovo[i] != '\0'` is easier to understand for a beginner. And yes, `scanf("%20s", slova)` is better, but who cares for toy programs?

Comment: @Jabberwocky i dont know how many words there will be, i just know that max lenght of word is 20

Comment: @EvaSedláková maybe you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28179122) and add some examples of input and expected output. The code in my answer asks for one word, and then reverse prints it.

Comment: %20s can overflow..

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, but this is a toy program

Comment: I don't think this is OPs program, but the original incorrect one from the assignment

Comment: @AnttiHaapala actually I'm not sure anymore what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: you should just have cast a cv.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure that I understood what should the program do, but here is a program that ask you to give some characters and then it display them in backward :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void naopak(char slovo[20], int n)
{
    printf("here is your caracters in backward \n");
    for(int i=n; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c ",slovo[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char slova[20];
    int n;
    printf("number of caracters ?: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       printf("give carater %d: ",i);
       scanf("%s",&slova[i]);
    }

    naopak(slova,n);

    return 0;
 }
```

Example of use :

number of caracters ?: 5
give carater 0: a
give carater 1: b
give carater 2: c
give carater 3: d
give carater 4: e
here is your caracters in backward
e d c b a

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86RxW.png)

Comment: You don't need to post a picture of text that is already in your answer